# Looking for high quality small speakers for my home

Tags: speakers

I spend most of my time programming in my work room, and would like to enjoy my lossless, audiophile music without having to crank up the whole neighbourhood.

Something that can sound very good and high-end on very low volumes, without me having to put headphones.

Doesn't anybody know of some good brands or models that I should look into?

**Note**: I'm looking more into stereo speakers. Don't need all these 5/7.1 sets...

Comment: This site is for Audio Recording and Production; home stereo systems are off-topic here.

Comment: You might consider also asking on the SE 1.0 site [home4film](http://home4film.com/), or supporting the Area 51 [Home Theater](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2274/home-theater) proposal.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice Home4Film existed. I'll move the quetion there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually settled for an [Audioengine A2 speakers](http://audioengineusa.com/Store/Powered-Speaker-Systems/A2-plus-W-Powered-Desktop-Speakers). Very high quality relative to its price.

Answer (score 2):

[HP USB Mini Speakers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027JLIVM) are reputed to pack a good punch for their size.

[M-Audio Studiophile monitors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MUXJCO) are a good fit if you're OK with the price.